# Run gradle from PHP file

Tags: php, android, gradle, command-line

I am trying to compile an android app from a PHP file:

```
<?php

$command = "sh build.sh";
$output = shell_exec($command);

print $output;
?>
```

My file build.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

export JAVA_HOME=/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/android-sdk/jdk1.8.0_73/
export PATH=${PATH}:${JAVA_HOME}/bin

export GRADLE_HOME=/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/android-sdk/gradle-2.11/
export PATH=${PATH}:${GRADLE_HOME}/bin

export GRADLE_USER_HOME=/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/workspace/gradle_user_home/

gradle --info --debug build 2>&1
```

When I open the PHP file in the browser, I get this error:

```
* What went wrong: 00:45:56.317 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Failed to load native library 'libnative-platform.so' for Linux amd64.
```

If instead of Shell_exec I use exec() it shows just this:

```
[ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
```

If I run gradle from the command line, everything works fine, I think the issue must be with the user, with shell_exec() the gradle command is exectuted with apache user, but I can not find a solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?